# explorer.exe crashes when computer boots

Tags: crash

every time user logs into windows 10, explorer.exe error appears on screen.
Here are event viewer error:

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f3c97
Faulting module name: SHELL32.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f3ee0
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000005bf22c
Faulting process id: 0x1560
Faulting application start time: 0x01d20c06cdc85bdb
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
Report Id: 6cf96e26-c5ea-441f-b721-13d85fa882ce
Faulting package full name:
```

I tried to login with different user, the problem is not there. The third user gets no explorer.exe notification, but start button do not work.
Tried sfc scannow and  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth with no luck

EDIT: safe mode gives same error

Comment: Have you tried safemode? If it works normally in safemode, try cleanbooting your machine. If it still works, slowly start enabling application at startup and restart.

If it doenst work in safemode, it is truly corrupt and you made need to restore or do a fresh install.

You could also try coping shell32 from another computer and replacing the current version.

Comment: safe mode same error, if I copy shell32 from another computer i get destination folder access denied